# Both sorted and unsorted glossaries with glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, subdividing, nomenclature

Using the `glossaries` package, is it possible to have two glossaries:

1. one unsorted (i.e., in order of appearance/use) such as for an index of notation, and
2. the other sorted alphabetically such as for a glossary of terminology?

   If so, how?

Note: I also require that the glossary of notation be subdivided into groups. I know how to do that with just one glossary, but will the usual method interfere if I also have the 2nd kind of glossary?

In case it matters, I'm using the `memoir` documentclass.

Comment: Since there are two commands, `\makeglossaries` and `\makeindex`I'm not sure if you need to try and create two different sorting schemes from `\printglossary[type=XXX,style=YYY]`. The glossaries package can also put the page numbers your item is used on with your sorted entry.  The only other way of sorting a glossary that I am aware of offhand, is through the `sort={}` field in `\newglossaryentry` which is somewhat manual, but with a custom style that prints the page numbers, would give you what you describe, even though it's not nice and automatic.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary` instead of `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossary` if you want different sorting rules. The `noidx` variant uses TeX to sort and collate rather than using `makeindex` or `xindy`. It would've helped to have had a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate the type of entries you have. The following example uses dummy entries provided in the test files `example-glossaries-brief.tex` and `example-glossaries-symbols.tex` which should be installed with `glossaries.sty`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makenoidxglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}
\loadglsentries[symbols]{example-glossaries-symbols}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary[sort=word,style=mcolindexgroup]
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=def,style=index]

\end{document}
```

The main glossary is sorted according to word order:

[image: image of glossary sample]

The symbols glossary is unsorted, although it looks sorted in this example simply because the sample entries were defined in that order. Another option is `sort=use` which orders the entries according to the first use in the document. [There are many different predefined glossary styles to choose from.](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/)

Note that the [`noidx` method](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) is very inefficient at sorting alphabetically and is only designed for ASCII. The `glossaries-extra` extension package allows a mix and match approach so that `makeindex`/`xindy` may be used for the alphabetical sorting and `\printnoidxglossary` can be used for order of definition or order of use. (With `sort=def` or `sort=use`, `\printnoidxglossary` simply iterates through an internal list, which means no actual sorting is performed).

Adjusted example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makeglossaries[main]

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}
\loadglsentries[symbols]{example-glossaries-symbols}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=mcolindexgroup]
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=def,style=index]

\end{document}
```

If you use `makeglossaries`, it will detect that `makeindex` is only required for the `main` glossary.