# How to sort abbreviations alphabetically and symbols based on page number?

Tags: glossaries

I've generated my list of symbols as follows:

```
\usepackage[sort=use]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{gloss}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}% <-- change the value here
        {\end{longtable}}%
}
```

And here is my `gloss.tex` file:

```
\newglossaryentry{DES}{name={ABC}, description={AAA BBB CCC}}
\newglossaryentry{SCT}{name={DEF}, description={DDD EEE FFF}}
\newglossaryentry{ReEV}{name={\ensuremath{\sigma}}, description={S}}
\newglossaryentry{sync}{name={\ensuremath{\parallel}},description={P}}
```

The output exactly follows the `[sort=use]`, and the list is printed like:

```
S     page:1
DEF   page:2
P     page:3
ABC   page:4
```

But I need to first have abbreviations sorted alphabetically, then symbols sorted based on page number:

```
ABC   page:4
DEF   page:2
P     page:3
S     page:1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem instead of snippets of code. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, (**note:**) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Both sorted and unsorted glossaries with glossaries package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339361/both-sorted-and-unsorted-glossaries-with-glossaries-package). Just replace `sort=def` with `sort=use` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339389/19862).